# vue-cli can't find global npm package

Tags: vue.js, unix, npm, vagrant

I'm using nvm to manage npm. This within a vagrant ubuntu/bionic64 container.

My global node_modules are in `/home/vagrant`

and my project is in `/vagrant`, the default synced vagrant folder.

When I do `vue create myproject` I get:

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path /vagrant/project/myproject/node_modules/@soda/friendly-errors-webpack-plugin/node_modules/string-width/node_modules/ansi-regex/package.json.2916702147
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/vagrant/project/myproject/node_modules/@soda/friendly-errors-webpack-plugin/node_modules/string-width/node_modules/ansi-regex/package.json.2916702147'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
```

But `ansi-regex` can be found globally in:
`/home/vagrant/.nvm/versions/node/v14.2.0/bin`

When I did `vue create myproject` in `/home/vagrant` it worked! But I would like to have my project in the default shared vagrant folder `/vagrant`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vagrant doesn't support symlinks for the synced folder. Add this to your Vagrant file.

```
config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
    # Enable symlinks in vagrant shared folder, https://coderwall.com/p/b5mu2w
    v.customize ["setextradata", :id, "VBoxInternal2/SharedFoldersEnableSymlinksCreate/v-root", "1"]
    v.customize ["setextradata", :id, "VBoxInternal2/SharedFoldersEnableSymlinksCreate/vagrant-root", "1"]
    v.customize ["setextradata", :id, "VBoxInternal2/SharedFoldersEnableSymlinksCreate/vagrant", "1"]
end
```